# Why is declaring doctype html preventing event drag or touch to trigger?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, meta-tags

When declaring doctype html my code stops working, so no event drag or touch is triggered.

I'm working in a prototype to drag an image element inside a container element, to crop it. I'll also implement pinch to zoom, etc. To make this work better on mobile browsers, I need to set this in the head of the document, which helps preventing double taps and other unwanted event triggering:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You can find a working example, without doctype being declared:

http://jsbin.com/cokil/5

If I do declare doctype and put the meta viewport it stops working, but I can't seem to understand why:

http://jsbin.com/cokil/4

It's also been tested, just adding the doctype and no meta viewport. Won't work at all!

Any tips or advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a `DOCTYPE`, your page tells the browser to render the page strictly. If you simply omit the declaration, it will instead use the so called [Quirksmode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

So obviously your code does not comply with HTML 5 strict-mode which is used when you add `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I hope this is the advice you needed.

**EDIT:**

I found what causes your script from working. In your `drag`-Event: simply replace your old lines with:

```
imgEl.style.top = y + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaY)+'px';
imgEl.style.left = x + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaX)+'px';
```

The strict mode requires you to return numeric values that are followed by a `px` just like you are defining it in your style attribute: `style="top:0px; left:0px;"`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that by concatenating + "px" fixes the issue:

```
        Hammer(element).on("drag", function(event) {

            imgEl.style.top = y + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaY) + "px";
            imgEl.style.left = x + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaX) + "px";

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that there is no html errors or the rendering will use the quirksmode even if you specify a doctype.

You can use this service to check the validity of your page: http://validator.w3.org/check